# Dynamic repetition for a list or df of file directories

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, elementtree

So I have working code for searching for files I want in a directory. I can save them as a dataframe or a list. I then figured out how to do findall(),find().text to get tags and texts from one single xml file. I want to now make it more dynamic to a set of values equal to the position in this dataframe or list. **I am getting an error message of "expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not tuple."  I want to know where is my understanding wrong in this code or where is my understanding a little off?** I also am not sure if maybe I am over complicating it with a dataframe and should just use a list.
.....

```
import os  
import pandas as pd
import os  
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

.....
current_dur = r'Workplace Investing'
#empty data frame to put the file paths in.
file_results = []    

#logic to search through the directories.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dur):
    for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.ldm') or file.endswith('.cdm') or file.endswith('.pdm'):
                file_results.append(os.path.join(root, file))           

filesdataframe = pd.DataFrame(file_results)
filesdataframe.rename(columns = { 0 :'Directory Path'}, inplace = True)

......


#In my working code I set the xmlfile equal to a single directory path.
#This worked for one file. Now my thinking is maybe I set xmlfile equal to dataframe.iterrows().
#That way when I make my loop it will go by each row. 
xmlfile = next(filesdataframe.iterrows())

for ind in filesdataframe.index:
    #This is next line is where I am getting my issue. 
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
   
    root = tree.getroot()
.....
```

Comment: I edited it. I hope this is not to much.

Comment: Yes, I think you are overcomplicating it by adding the filepaths to a dataframe. That seems unnecessary.

Comment: `xmlfile = next(filesdataframe.iterrows())` makes `xmlfile` a tuple. [DataFrame.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html?highlight=iterrows#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows): Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.